# Jetpack Compose beta cannot go edge-to-edge due to overriding fitsSystemWindows

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-immersive

I have upgraded Compose for my app from `1.0.0-alpha10` to current latest of `1.0.0-beta03`

I want to layout my activity contents edge to edge, underneath system bars.

Among other things I have used the below code to tell the system this intent.

```kotlin
window?.run {
    WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(this, false)
}
```

This has worked well in the previous Compose version, but it seems like `beta03` (or may be an earlier version after `alpha10`) started setting `fitsSystemWindows` to `true` and makes the above code ineffective. (Moving it below `setContent { }` had no effect either)

In the Layout Explorer I can see the `decorView` and its direct child `LinearLayout` now has `fitsSystemWindows = true`

I have below code as a temp solution which works to get the expected behavior.

```kotlin
// code that used to work on alpha10        
window?.run {
    WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(this, false)
}

setContent {
   MyApp()
}

// temp workaround for beta03
window?.decorView?.fitsSystemWindows = false
window?.decorView?.allViews?.forEach { view ->
    view.fitsSystemWindows = false
}
```

This feels like I'm fighting against Compose for the desired result.

What is the "correct" way to tell Compose not to override `fitsSystemWindows`?

Comment: https://google.github.io/accompanist/insets/

Comment: I don't think it would work. Page says > 

This library does not disable window decor fitting. For your view hierarchy to able to receive insets, you need to make sure to call: WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false) from your Activity.

Which is what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Did you try the example e2e provided? It works with beta04 without issues

Comment: sorry. Didn't knew beta04 was out. will upgrade and try.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti Sorry I tried with beta04 and still doesn't work. I tried accompanist which also didn't help. Issue is not getting the window inset values, but setting fitsSystemWindows, which accompanist doesn't do anyway.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using splash api first write splash then edge to edge like this:

```
overide fun onCreate(savedInstancesState)
installSplashScreen()
enableEdgeToEdge()
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
```

Answer (score -1):

I currently have edge to edge implemented using the following:

Firstly in your res > theme remove action bar;

```
<style name="Theme.app_android" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
```

Then call my composable in MainActivity, setting WindowCompat before as shown below

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)
    setContent {
         App()
       }
    }
 }
```

Then using the ProvideWindowInsets function to remember a systemUiController that's called inside a SideEffect function that sets the system status bar to transparent

```
@Composable
fun App() {
    AppTheme {
        ProvideWindowInsets {
            val systemUiController = rememberSystemUiController()

            SideEffect {
                systemUiController.setSystemBarsColor(Color.Transparent, 
                darkIcons = false)
            }

            val navController = rememberNavController()
            val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
            val navBackStackEntry by 
            navController.currentBackStackEntryAsState()
            val currentRoute = navBackStackEntry?.destination?.route

            Scaffold() { innerPadding ->
                Box(modifier = Modifier.padding(innerPadding)) {
                    NavGraph(navController = navController)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you clone the compose samples from here https://github.com/android/compose-samples they show you this way to implement it